# CakePHP 1.3: Issue with saveField

Tags: cakephp

I dont understand why I am not able to update a field on the database based on the following code:

```
$this->User->id = 1;
$this->User->saveField('image','img/default_pic.png');
```

Basically, I want to change the current image in the Db with a new one.

The code above just clears the value that is currently in the `image` field, but does not add anything.

As an example, this is what happens:

```
id    username    image
=============================
1     admin       mypic.jpg
2     john        johnPic.jpg
```

After the code above is executed I get the following result

```
id    username    image
=============================
1     admin       
2     john        johnPic.jpg
```

I am confused at what is actually happening

Comment: Try this :
$this->User->id = 1;
$this->User->saveField('image','default_pic.png');

Comment: It doesnt work either... I dont get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!

I decided to go back and check on my `user.php` model class and realized that I had attempted to use `MeioUpload` before and gave up, but I never removed the `var actsAs` entry.

As soon as I commented it out, I am now able to upload pictures.

For anyone else that might come across this issue, `beforeSave` might also caused these kind of problems, according to the following blog: http://blog.phplabs.net/2011/11/cakephp-savefield-not-working.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What does the sql log say is happening?

My guess is you are actually doing something like

```
$this->User->saveField('image', $variable)
```

and `$variable` is either misspelled or is empty.

Comment: I thought, which is why I tried with an actual string. The code you see on my question is the actual code I am using. I will check mysql dump to find out what is going on

Comment: It is submitted via jQuery and I dont know how to accomplish a `sql_dump` like that. I tried `CakeLog::write('debug', $this->element('sql_dump'));` but it does not write anything.

Comment: FIXED!. `user.php` model, `actsAs` problem. Check my answer above.... Thanks for helping though